# How to display a ImageView pixelated without interpolating low res files?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, pixel, android-image

I want to load a ImageView with a png file with low resolution. I want to display the pixels but the ImageView is displaying it blurry with interpolation. How can this be avoided? I want to display all the pixels.

This is the way I'm displaying the ImageView:

```
Drawable dr = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cloud);
Bitmap cloud1Bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) dr).getBitmap();
float cloud1Ratio = (float)cloud1Bitmap.getHeight()/cloud1Bitmap.getWidth();
        
cloud1ImageView = new ImageView(this);
cloud1ImageView.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
cloud1ImageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(cloud1Bitmap, cloud1Width, (int) (cloud1Width*cloud1Ratio), true));
main.addView(cloud1ImageView);
```

### Edit

Tried with that function and didn't work. Maybe it's because I'm scaling the image?

```
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    
    width = (int) (sw/3);
    Drawable dr = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ufo);
    BitmapDrawable bd = ((BitmapDrawable) dr);
    Bitmap bitmap = bd.getBitmap();
    float ratio = (float)bitmap.getHeight()/bitmap.getWidth();
    height = (int)(width*ratio);

    BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, false));
    drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);        
    view.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

In the left you can see how the image appears on the game and in the right how is in the original png:

[image]

Comment: Can you show image effect that you want?

Comment: @pskink it's a game, i need to scale the bitmaps to use exactly the required dimensions in memory

Comment: can you add a demo of what do you mean?

Comment: ok I tryed with this but the same blurry filter is being applyed, please test it: view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams((int) (sw/3f), RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
  view.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
  view.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Comment: a super small ufo image, can't appreciate the pixels, it's super small, 32x24 or something. I need to scale it to 1/3 of the width of the creen to apreciate the pixels

Comment: yes, but I'm adding into a relativelayout instead of setContentView. Remember that my image is very small, maybe you are using a big image

Comment: nope, I'm adding it to my layout which match parent all the screen

Answer (score 2):

As @pskink says, you can stop the blurring/interpolation by calling `setFilterBitmap(false)`. For these examples, I'm using a 24px image in a 240dp ImageView:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_android);
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);

ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

[image]

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_android);
BitmapDrawable drawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
drawable.setFilterBitmap(false);

ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

[image]

Comment: but what happens if you need to scale the image to a desired size like I need. You can see it in my sample code. I tryed adding that function and nothing happens. Maybe is because of the scale?